# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - After software update prime-select doesn't work

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel

Prime-select tells that I use nvidia but that is not true

It was working very well past 1-2 months but after software update i cant use external monitor anymore (Acer Nitro 5 - HDMI connected only to nvidia gtx1060)

Installing different drivers 440/435/390 doesn't change anything. Previous kernel also runs only on Intel. Tried restarting

```
szymon@szymon-nitro:~$ glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
szymon@szymon-nitro:~$ prime-select query
nvidia


... some info below ...


szymon@szymon-nitro:~$ inxi -SMGxx
System:
  Host: szymon-nitro Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Nitro AN515-52 v: V1.19 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: CFL model: Freed_CFS v: V1.19 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Insyde v: 1.19 date: 07/13/2018 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3e9b 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
  chip ID: 10de:1c20 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa compositor: gnome-shell 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 
  direct render: Yes 
szymon@szymon-nitro:~$ uname -a
Linux szymon-nitro 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```